# linux shell script sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

```
#!/bin/sh -x

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]];then
   echo "usage: makeSoln <customer name>"
   exit
fi

echo "Customer Name is set to : $1"

if [ -d "$1" ]; then
    echo "Solution for $1 already exists!! Please delete it before running this."
    exit 1;
fi

if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    echo "A file by name '$1' exists!! Please delete it before running this."
    exit 1;
fi

cp -R SolnTemplate $1

cd $1

find . -name "pom.xml" | xargs sed -i xx 's/SolnTemplate/'$1'/g'
```

When i given this  and execute this file i am gettting this error:

```
+ xargs sed -e xx s/SolnTemplate/Reliance/g
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command
```

Comment: From the error message, it looks like you have `sed -e xx` rather than `sed -i xx`.

Answer (score 1):

To begin, replace:

```
find . -name "pom.xml" | xargs sed -i xx 's/SolnTemplate/'$1'/g'
```

With:

```
find . -name "pom.xml" | xargs sed -ixx 's/SolnTemplate/'$1'/g'
```

The above removes the space between `-i` and `xx`.  Because you are on Linux, you are using GNU sed and, unlike BSD sed, it does not accept a space between -i and the backup suffix.

Also, just in case `$1` includes a space in the name, it should be enclosed in double-quotes:

```
find . -name "pom.xml" | xargs sed -ixx 's/SolnTemplate/'"$1"'/g'
```

This still requires care that you don't unintentionally include any sed-active characters in `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

i didnt go over all of the script, but this command:

```
sed -i xx 's/SolnTemplate/'$1'/g'
```

should be:

```
sed -ixx 's/SolnTemplate/"$1"/g'
```

because the `'` is from outside, you need to put in the inside `"`